# Nginx: Listen to Specific host's specific port and do proxy_pass for that host:port only

Tags: nginx

I've been hitting a wall for 3 days on this. Allow me to explain the matter:

We have a domain named `demo1.example.com`. We want `demo1.example.com:90` to do proxy pass for `123.123.123.123:90`, but not any other vhosts in the server like `demo2.example.com`.

What I mean is, that port should only work for that vhost, if someone tries to access `demo2.example.com:90`, it should not work. Currently, it is doing proxy_pass for any vhosts:90.

I hope I have explained the situation and that there is an actual solution for this.

Here's my current code:

```
server {
    listen ip:80;
    server_name subdomain.url.here;
   and other normal server stuff for port 80
}
server {
    listen ip:90;
    location / {
         proxy_pass 123.123.123.123:90;
         proxy_set_header                 Host $host:$server_port;
    }
}
```

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try to add a serverName to your configuration?

Comment: Hi @night-gold, thanks for replying. Could you explain a bit? `server_name`? Yes. I've omitted that part from the `listen ip:80` part for brevity.

Comment: I saw the "normal server stuff..." But why not use it also in for the listen ip:90...

Comment: I have done that with and without, it produces the same result.